# How to check user-agent in ASP.NET Core health check calls (MapHealthChecks)?

Tags: asp.net-core

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check it is noted that

> Large enterprise development teams often need to adhere to security requirements for exposed APIs. To secure the Health check endpoint, you should first use features such as IP restrictions, client certificates, or a Virtual Network to restrict application access. You can secure the Health check endpoint by requiring the User-Agent of the incoming request matches ReadyForRequest/1.0. The User-Agent can't be spoofed since the request would already secured by prior security features.

How could one do this check user-agent in practice? I'm thinking the code

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions { AllowCachingResponses = false });
});
```

and then in Azure the WebApp would check it's a call originating from Azure service and not from public Internet before replying (and just dropping the call otherwise). I understand there are better ways to do this on the edge, though.

What I think is that the option that came to my mind would be to write a [middlware component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0) do check both the URL and agent. Though maybe I miss something obvious and this is not the way? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which performs user agent requirement validation

```
public class UserAgentRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string UserAgent { get; }

    public UserAgentRequirement(string userAgent)
    {
        UserAgent = userAgent;
    }
}

public class UserAgentAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserAgentRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public UserAgentAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserAgentRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        
        var agent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
        if (agent == requirement.UserAgent)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Do not forget to register `IHttpContextAccessor` and `UserAgentAuthorizationHandler`. In **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserAgentAuthorizationHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    //...
    options.AddPolicy("HealthCheckPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AddRequirements(new UserAgentRequirement("ReadyForRequest/1.0"));
    });
});

//...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints
        .MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions { AllowCachingResponses = false })
        .RequireAuthorization("HealthCheckPolicy");
    //...
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me. I was expecting the /health path to not work locally, but it does. For context, I am adding the healthcheck to an existing startup file, which has a lot of existing configuration.

Comment: @JimmyIsaac **I was expecting the /health path to not work locally, but it does. ** How did you try to achieve this?

Comment: I wrote a couple of classes that implemented IHealthCheck, and in startup added code suggested by you and following:  services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck<HealthCheckFoo>("health_check_foo")
                .AddCheck<HealthCheckBar>("health_check_bar");

Locally, https://localhost:5001/health returns 'healthy'. 

I ran the code in a deployed environment, and the health check using App Services both fails and passes as expected. However, I think the user-agent requirement is not being enforced.

Comment: @JimmyIsaac I'm not sure if I can help you without seeing actual implementation. Consider creating a question on the site and ping me here. Thanks

Comment: Also, moot point - instead of ReadyForRequest/1.0 used HealthCheck/1.0 as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check#authentication-and-security)

Comment: I have posted a separate question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328609/how-to-check-user-agent-in-asp-net-core-health-check-calls-when-using-own-not-a