# How to check user-agent in ASP.NET Core health check calls when using own authentication, authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-agent, health-check

I used the accepted answer to [How to check user-agent in ASP.NET Core health check calls (MapHealthChecks)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654787/how-to-check-user-agent-in-asp-net-core-health-check-calls-maphealthchecks) , with one difference in requirement:

My application is not using App services authentication and authorization. Therefore, I needed to allow anonymous access for healthcheck as per  [documentation](http://How%20to%20check%20user-agent%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core%20health%20check%20calls%20when%20using%20own%20(not%20App%20Services%20authentication/authorization)?).

Here are changes to Startup.cs

```
             //other services

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserAgentAuthorizationHandler>();
            services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck<HealthCheckFoo>("health_check_foo")
                .AddCheck<HealthCheckBar>("health_check_bar");

             //other  services.AddAuthorization
            
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HealthCheckPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddRequirements(new UserAgentRequirement("HealthCheck/1.0"));
                });
            });

            //...
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
                 //other endpoints...

                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions { AllowCachingResponses = false })
                         .RequireAuthorization("HealthCheckPolicy");
                         .WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute());
```

My expectation is that when testing locally, https://localhost:5001/health return an error. It does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as your startup class has a mistake on the `endpoints.MapHealthChecks` adds a `RequireAuthorization` but as the same time you also add the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.

Try with:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    AllowCachingResponses = false,
                })
                .RequireAuthorization("HealthCheckPolicy");
        });
```